# ADUC from non domain PC

Tags: active-directory, permissions

I'm trying to run ADUC from PC that are not joined to domain, I created delegation for specified user, I have DNS pointed to domain controller, I can RDP to it and have full connectivity. But when I try run ADUC, using .bat file

```
runas /u:<DOMAIN_B>\<USER> /netonly mmc
```

and then run ADUC I get an error:

```
Naming Information cannot be located because: The specified domain either doesn’t exist or could not be contacted.
```

so is any way to configure technician computer that are not joined to domain? I need this for reset user passwords.

Comment: `The specified domain either doesn’t exist or could not be contacted`.  Seems like a straightforward name resolution issue.

Comment: It'll use DOMAIN_B as the lookup so be sure you are using the DNS Domain Name and not the NetBIOS Domain Name, you should also be able to perform a successful `nslookup` of DOMAIN_B from the client running the command.

Comment: I have the same error no matter what name I use: NETBIOS "mycompany" or
FQDN "dc01.mycompany.local"

Comment: Surely dc01.mycompany.local is not the domain FQDN but the Domain Controller FQDN. Try using just mycompany.local\<Username>.

Answer (score 2):

I used this for a long time on Windows 10, but recently upgraded to Windows 11 and it doesn't seem to be working anymore:

```
@echo off
runas /netonly /user:domain\user "mmc /server=domaincontroller.domain"
```

Answer (score 0):

All I have done is is made a one line batch file with the following:

- dsa.msc /Domain=internal domain FQDN

I then run that batch file with my onprem domain creds and it opens up.  This is on Windows 11.

[cmd prompt with aduc.msc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYxdl.png)